# How to structure the data in dynamoDB, nested dictionaries or multiple items?

Tags: database, dictionary, data-structures, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am aggregating from XML generated by our automation tests, I am using python in a lambda function to parse the XML and create a dynamoDB item.

In the end, I need the date of each test run the test duration and will be calculating some basic stats such as mean, stdev, etc.

Currently, I am using a very flat structure:

```
{
  "testName": string
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "testEndedAt": timecode,
  "testStartedAt": timecode,
  "testRunID": string,
  "timeAdded": time,
  "totalTime": number
}
```

Each test run generated a new item with the same test name.

I am using testName and testrunID as the primary and sort keys.

I have a sense that the way I'm doing something is inefficient. I am considering moving to a data structure like this:

```
{
    testname:string,
    tests:[
            {
                timeAdded:timeStamp
                testRunId:string,
                testStartedAt:number,
                testEndedAt:number,
                totalTime:number
            }
            {
                timeAdded:timeStamp
                testRunId:string,
                m__testStartedAt:number,
                m__testEndedAt:number,
                totalTime:number
            }
    ],
    stats:{
        mean:number
        stDev:number
        maxExpectedTime:number
    }
}
```

I see a couple of advantages in this approach.

I store the calculated stats in the table
I can use a test name and a unique key
I don't have to scan the entire DB to calculate stats etc

Having little experience with this I don't know how best to approach the question let alone answer it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using the original structure:

```
{
  "testName": string
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "testEndedAt": timecode,
  "testStartedAt": timecode,
  "testRunID": string,
  "timeAdded": time,
  "totalTime": number
}
```

This way you can easily query (not scan) for all testRuns with a particular testName. Using the query results, you can then do your aggregate operations and save it back to the same table with a different GSI. (partition key as testName).

```
{
  "testName": string
  "mean": "number",
  "stDev": number,
  "maxExpectedTime": number
}
```

If you want these aggregate stats to be realtime, enable and send streams for this table to a lambda function. Increment/update these aggregate metrics according to the new data coming in.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I really should be using Query more than scan when I can. I need to learn more about GSI. 

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4):

Never ever is it a good idea to do something like:
**tests**:[...] with rows being added inside tests thereafter.

Why?

1. To add a new row in tests you have to read the item, push to the array and save back. There is an extra read for each write.
2. Since you're reading the data and writing it back its poasible to simultaneously read / write the **tests** attribute, resulting in data loss. Ive seen it happening.
3. There is an item size limit of 400k in dynamodb, so your tests array has limited number of rows that can be added.